How to use alias in LEFT JOIN with alasql?
This simple query works fine in MySQL, but fails in AlaSQL - why?
SELECT DISTINCT any_event.*, temp.event_name AS parent_name
FROM any_event
LEFT JOIN any_event AS temp ON any_event.parent_id=temp.event_id
WHERE any_event.event_id=3

The error code from AlaSQL is (shortened for readability):
SELECT any_event.*, temp.event_name AS p
--------------------^
Expecting 'LITERAL', 'BRALITERAL', 'LPAR', [.....] 'MINUS', 'ATLBRA', 'LCUR', got 'TEMP'

Tried it with AlaSQL versions 4.3.1 and 3.0.0.

This appears to a known and existing issue: https://github.com/AlaSQL/alasql/issues/357 ... check your column names to make sure that none of them are reserved keywords.

I saw that bug report, but none of my column names are reserved keywords.

Appearantly, "temp" IS a reserved keyword in AlaSQL (though it's not mentioned anywhere). When I switch "temp" with "tmp", everything works as expected. Go figure!

Appearantly, "temp" is a reserved keyword in AlaSQL. When I switch "temp" with "tmp", everything works as expected.
Edit:
Correct code:
SELECT DISTINCT any_event.*, tmp.event_name AS parent_name
FROM any_event
LEFT JOIN any_event AS tmp ON any_event.parent_id=tmp.event_id
WHERE any_event.event_id=3


Please include the corrected code as well to make this a complete answer.
